# Looking for a classic paper "Vinner and Hershkowitz"

Tags: reference-request, geometry

I can't find this ZDM article:

> Vinner, S., & Hershkowitz, R. (1983). On concept formation in geometry. *Zentralblatt für Didaktik der mathematik*, 83(1), 20-25.

Could you help me?

I was searching in some sites, but no success.

For example, in this one, it isn't available: http://www.emis.de/journals/ZDM/zdmcont.html

Comment: Did you try contacting Vinner and/or Hershkowitz directly? Alternatively, you might check [**who**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2011&hl=en&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&cites=14428030072932834745&scipsc=) recently cited the paper to see if one of these authors has a copy that can be easily communicated. (I did a reasonably thorough search for it just now and came up with nothing...)

Comment: I can't seem to find it in any of the online resources I normally search.  Do you have access to inter-library loan resources through a university library?

Comment: yes, I looked fof the paper in university libraries, but no succes. I´m trying Benjamin options . Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to get it through Inter-Library Loan.  I'll let you know if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, the author posted it in www.researchgate.net

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284382026_On_concept_formation_in_geometry

Thank you to all.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but that article is *not* the one you were asking for.  Although the researchgate page has the right name, the actual PDF linked there has a different title, different page numbers, and does not have Vinner as a co-author.